# ComboxBox in an editable Grid

Tags: javascript, jsp, extjs4, java-ee-6

I am new in ExtJS and now I am making an editable grid with a combox column. I am having a problem in displaying my chosen data from the combobox. May someone help me. Screenshot is provided below.

[image: http://dc532.4shared.com/img/KXKZShxg/s7/0.8332573228065803/error2.png?async]

[Link provided.. :))](http://dc532.4shared.com/img/KXKZShxg/s7/0.8332573228065803/error2.png?async)

My combobox code...

Data:

```
    var farms = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: ['id', 'farms'],
    data : [                                         
            ['1', 'DVZ'],
            ['2', 'SSK'],
            ['3', 'LNA'],
            ['4', 'NSK']
           ]
     });
```

Combobox..

```
 header   : 'Location',
          width    : 130,
          fixed    : true,
          hideable : false,
          dataIndex: 'farms',
          editor   : {xtype:'combo', 
                      store: farms,
                             displayField:'farms',
                             valueField: 'id',
                             queryMode: 'local',
                            typeAhead: true,
                            triggerAction: 'all',
                            lazyRender: true,
                            emptyText: 'Select location...',
                            autoload: true

          }
```

Comment: Show us your combobox code with grid code.

Comment: @Ankit: I already added the code for combobox.. :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be missing some "config" in editor config of items in grid panel.

I hope you may missed typeAhead config.

Please refer below link of sencha example

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/extjs-build/examples/grid/cell-editing.html

Thanks.

Comment: The link truly helped me.. Just figured out that my dataIndex should be the name of my header.. What I did was mydataIndex was my store.. xD Thanks a bunch...

Answer (score 1):

it's might be that your dataindex value in grid config, not same like you value field in  combobox config
for example, look at this config on "Responsible" field

```
columns: [
     { header: 'ID', dataIndex: 'id', width: 50, hidden: true, sortable: true },
     {header: 'Responsible',
            width: 175,
            sortable: true,
            renderer: title_respU_D1,
            dataIndex: 'resp_user_name'
            ,editor: new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                   typeAhead: true,
                   triggerAction: 'all',
                   store: app_responsibleStore,
                   mode: 'remote',
                   valueField: 'resp_user_name',
                   displayField: 'resp_user_name',
                   listClass: 'x-combo-list-small'
        })
     }

]
```